# Make dropdown stay on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website for a school project and have a small amount of coding experience from before. I have heard that it is possible to use only CSS to achieve a dropdown menu  without using JavaScript.

I'm having trouble making the dropdown stay on hover, it dissappears when the mouse goes down to the `li` element:

```css
/* Configuration of menu width */
html body ul.sf-menu ul,
html body ul.sf-menu ul li {
  width: 200px;
}
html body ul.sf-menu ul ul {
  margin: 0 0 0 200px;
}
/* Framework for proper showing/hiding/positioning */

ul.sf-menu,
ul.sf-menu * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.sf-menu {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
ul.sf-menu li {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
ul.sf-menu li:hover {
  visibility: inherit;
  /* fixes IE7 'sticky bug' */
}
ul.sf-menu a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
ul.sf-menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  top: auto;
  left: -999999px;
}
ul.sf-menu ul a {
  zoom: 1;
  /* IE6/7 fix */
}
ul.sf-menu ul li {
  float: left;
  /* Must always be floated otherwise there will be a rogue 1px margin-bottom in IE6/7 */
  width: 150px;
}
ul.sf-menu ul ul {
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 150px;
}
ul.sf-menu li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li:focus ul,
ul.sf-menu li.sf-hover ul,
ul.sf-menu ul li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu ul li:focus ul,
ul.sf-menu ul li.sf-hover ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul li:focus ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul li.sf-hover ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul ul li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul ul li:focus ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul ul li.sf-hover ul {
  left: auto;
}
ul.sf-menu li:hover ul ul,
ul.sf-menu li:focus ul ul,
ul.sf-menu li.sf-hover ul ul,
ul.sf-menu ul li:hover ul ul,
ul.sf-menu ul li:focus ul ul,
ul.sf-menu ul li.sf-hover ul ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul li:hover ul ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul li:focus ul ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul li.sf-hover ul ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul ul li:hover ul ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul ul li:focus ul ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul ul li.sf-hover ul ul {
  left: -999999px;
}
/* autoArrows CSS */

span.sf-arrow {
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 5px;
  display: block;
  background: url(../images/arrows-white.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* making sure IE6 doesn't overflow and expand the box */
  font-size: 1px;
}
ul ul span.sf-arrow {
  right: 5px;
  top: 20px;
  background-position: 0 100%;
}
/* Theming the menu */

ul#nav {
  float: left;
}
ul#nav ul {
  background: #555;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
ul#nav li a {
  padding: 7px 25px 6px 25px;
  font: 170%'Yanone Kaffeesatz', arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
ul#nav li a:hover,
ul#nav li a:focus,
ul#nav li.selected a,
ul#nav li.selected a:hover,
ul#nav li.selected a:focus {
  color: #09D4FF;
  text-shadow: none;
}
ul#nav ul li a {
  color: #FFF;
}
ul#nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #09D4FF;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
/* Image Transitions */

ul#images {
  margin: 0 15px 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
ul#images li {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 155px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="sf-menu" id="nav">
    <li class="selected"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="form.html"> Form </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page.html">A Page</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="another_page.html">Another Page</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Example Drop Down</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down One</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down Two</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <img src="arrows-white.png" />
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Drop Down One</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Drop Down Two</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Drop Down Three</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Drop Down Four</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Drop Down Five</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down Three</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down Four</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down Five</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You can use http://cssmenumaker.com/css-drop-down-menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your issue is you just have to remove the `margin-top` from the `#nav` by here:-

```
ul#nav ul { 
  background: #555;
  //margin-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

That is causing a space between the hovered `li` and its child `ul` (dropdown) you are showing.

Working Code below

```css
html body ul.sf-menu ul,
html body ul.sf-menu ul li {
  width: 200px;
}
html body ul.sf-menu ul ul {
  margin: 0 0 0 200px;
}
/* Framework for proper showing/hiding/positioning */

ul.sf-menu,
ul.sf-menu * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.sf-menu {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
ul.sf-menu li {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
ul.sf-menu li:hover {
  visibility: inherit;
  /* fixes IE7 'sticky bug' */
}
ul.sf-menu a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
ul.sf-menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  top: auto;
  left: -999999px;
}
ul.sf-menu ul a {
  zoom: 1;
  /* IE6/7 fix */
}
ul.sf-menu ul li {
  float: left;
  /* Must always be floated otherwise there will be a rogue 1px margin-bottom in IE6/7 */
  width: 150px;
}
ul.sf-menu ul ul {
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 150px;
}
ul.sf-menu li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li:focus ul,
ul.sf-menu li.sf-hover ul,
ul.sf-menu ul li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu ul li:focus ul,
ul.sf-menu ul li.sf-hover ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul li:focus ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul li.sf-hover ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul ul li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul ul li:focus ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul ul li.sf-hover ul {
  left: auto;
}
ul.sf-menu li:hover ul ul,
ul.sf-menu li:focus ul ul,
ul.sf-menu li.sf-hover ul ul,
ul.sf-menu ul li:hover ul ul,
ul.sf-menu ul li:focus ul ul,
ul.sf-menu ul li.sf-hover ul ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul li:hover ul ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul li:focus ul ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul li.sf-hover ul ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul ul li:hover ul ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul ul li:focus ul ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul ul li.sf-hover ul ul {
  left: -999999px;
}
/* autoArrows CSS */

span.sf-arrow {
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 5px;
  display: block;
  background: url(../images/arrows-white.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* making sure IE6 doesn't overflow and expand the box */
  font-size: 1px;
}
ul ul span.sf-arrow {
  right: 5px;
  top: 20px;
  background-position: 0 100%;
}
/* Theming the menu */

ul#nav {
  float: left;
}
ul#nav ul {
  background: #555;
  //margin-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
ul#nav li a {
  padding: 7px 25px 6px 25px;
  font: 170%'Yanone Kaffeesatz', arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
ul#nav li a:hover,
ul#nav li a:focus,
ul#nav li.selected a,
ul#nav li.selected a:hover,
ul#nav li.selected a:focus {
  color: #09D4FF;
  text-shadow: none;
}
ul#nav ul li a {
  color: #FFF;
}
ul#nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #09D4FF;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
/* Image Transitions */

ul#images {
  margin: 0 15px 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
ul#images li {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 155px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="sf-menu" id="nav">
    <li class="selected"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="form.html"> Form </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page.html">A Page</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="another_page.html">Another Page</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Example Drop Down</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down One</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down Two</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <img src="arrows-white.png" />
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Drop Down One</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Drop Down Two</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Drop Down Three</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Drop Down Four</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Drop Down Five</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down Three</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down Four</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down Five</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by adding a class name to each `li` element that contains nested `ul`, say the class name for the `li` is `.has-nested-ul`, then we can control the `max-height` property -*we can use `height` but it has disadvantages*- just like this:

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/3zsz6fm2/1/)

```css
html body ul.sf-menu ul, html body ul.sf-menu ul li {
  width: 200px;
}
html body ul.sf-menu ul {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
html body ul.sf-menu li.has-nested-ul:hover ul {
  max-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="sf-menu" id="nav">
    <li class="selected"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="form.html"> Form </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page.html">A Page</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="another_page.html">Another Page</a>
    </li>
    <li class="has-nested-ul"><a href="#">Example Drop Down</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down One</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down Two</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <img src="arrows-white.png" />
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Drop Down One</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Drop Down Two</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Drop Down Three</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Drop Down Four</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Drop Down Five</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down Three</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down Four</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down Five</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```